# Arduino Voltage Reading Problem

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-pro-mini, voltage

I was trying made a gear indicator for my bike, with manually sensing the gear shift.  But failed, cause my bike has no separate "neutral" wire, instead there is gear sensor in-built...!! But not gear-position indicator...!!

The in-built sensor gives different output voltage at every gear.

It sounds good that all I need is just an Pro-mini & OLED.
But, facing problem with the voltage reading on Pro-mini.

When I checking with normal multimeter, the output voltage is very stable.

I tried with the simple voltage reading code.
And added the voltages ranges as shows on multimeter.

Later Checked with **Uno**, Reading is quite stable (+- 0.02V).

[image]

But, **Pro-mini** voltage reading is too sensitive.
Sometimes, in same gear position getting high voltage difference.
So, in result I doesn't getting a stable voltage reading or gear display.

[image]

1. **Need suggestion to make changes, so the pro-mini also read like the multimeter / Uno reads.**
   (Is this because of Pro-Mini doesn't have the Op-Amp in-built?)
2. **And, also, Why the serial output is around 1.5V, while no input in A0...?**

*PS: I didn't use voltage divider, because, gear sensor output voltage is below 5V.*

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I assume it's a 5V 16Mhz Pro mini. Make sure power doesn't go through the voltage regulator on the Pro Mini. Try a different Pro Mini. Try a different analog pin on the Pro Mini. Try out the UNO again, to make sure the sensors signal still stable. You could try averaging the results to get a more stable value, but that's more something you'd do if the signal isn't very stable.

Comment: Okay, now that's very quick... After searching & trying over weeks... Just changing the Analog pin works perfectly. (-_-) Feeling Dumb... Anyway, thank you very much...!!!

Comment: Another Question, The output gives around 1.5V without any input... Should I use 10K pull-down... or subtract that in programming?

Comment: as long as you get discrete values for each gear, i wouldn't try to rebalance the equation.

Comment: Ok. It stable, for no input at analog pin... But when I add the sensor output to A1, its again unstable. I connected multimeter & arduino together, no issue with multimeter, but the Pro-mini reading is messed up...!!!!!!

Comment: It's all OK now... I was using different grounds... After attaching it fully on bike power, it's working like charm... Thank you guys...